how to implement conditional implicit conversion for cpp03?
example:
#include <cstdio>

class Base {public: virtual ~Base() {}};
class Child : public Base {};

template<typename T> class IsBase { public: enum { Value = 0, }; };
template<> class IsBase<Base> { public: enum { Value = 1, }; };
template<> class IsBase<Child> { public: enum { Value = 1, }; };

template<typename T, int isBase = IsBase<T>::Value> class Access { };
template<typename T> class Access<T, 1> { public: typedef T Value; };

static void func(Base *) {}
static void func(const char *) {}

class Holder0 {
public:
    template<typename T>
    operator T *() const {return dynamic_cast<T *>(p);}
public:
    Holder0() : p(NULL) {}
private:
    Base *p;
};

class Holder1 {
public:
    template<typename T>
    operator typename Access<T>::Value *() const {return dynamic_cast<T *>(p);}
public:
    Holder1() : p(NULL) {}
private:
    Base *p;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Holder0 o0;
    func(o0);  // <= ambiguous
    Holder1 o1;
    func(o1);  // <= no matching function

    // other use case, works fine
    Base *p0 = o0;
    Child *p1 = o0;
    return 0;
}

what i want to do:

make func(o0) and func(o1) matches func(Base *) only (and any further class specialized by IsBase<>), but not for func(const char *)
compatible for cpp03 (which does not support partial specialization for functions (operator T() function) )

what happens:

func(o0) would cause ambiguous
func(o1) would cause no matching function

EDIT:
i have updated the example above to describe the question more clearly:

Holder0 is some polymorphic container similar to shared_ptr
actual content (i.e. Base) wants to be implicitly converted as Base or Child


There is no o2 in your example.

Unrelated: Change stdio.h to cstdio

T is not deducible from typename Wrapper<T>::Value. When considering templated conversion operators, if any template parameters can't be deduced (from default arguments or from the target type), the conversion operator can't be called.
You have to make T deducible. To avoid conversion to other pointer types, use SFINAE to disable the conversion operator for invalid T.
In C++11, you might do it like this:
class Object1 {
public:
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<IsDummy<T>::Value>::type* = nullptr>
    operator T *(void) const {return nullptr;}
};

However, default template arguments don't exist in C++03. You can't change to return type because operator std::enable_if_t<IsDummy<T>::value, T*> is also not deducible. The conversion operator also takes no non-object arguments.
That leaves one position left: the dynamic exception specification:
class Object1 {
public:
    template<typename T>
    operator T *(void) throw(typename std::enable_if<IsDummy<T>::Value, void*>::type) const {return NULL;}
};

(std::enable_if is relatively easy to implement, but this also has the downside that now your operator has a dynamic exception specification)
